# what list type which is mutable in kotlin can be used in java?

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

Having a lib created with kotlin, in it there is a function expected to be overriden by its descendent class, which takes a mutableList (expected to be modified in this function)

```
protected open fun makeDataForAdapter(itemsList: MutableList<Data>) : List<Data>{
    return itemsList // default behavior
}
```

the lib is used in a app with java, so the descendent class overrides it:

```
@Override
protected List<Data> makeDataForAdapter(MutableList<Data> itemsList) {
     ......
}
```

the compiler complains about `"cant resolve the MutableList"`

what list type which is mutable in kotlin can be used in java?

Comment: `List<Data>`... Just use Ctrl-I (Cmd-I on Mac), and IntelliJ will allow you to override methods, and will add the necessary code for you.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet, clicking Cmd-I  on where? I am using AndroidStudio, seems it does not anything?

Comment: Sorry, it's Ctrl-O, for Override method, in the Java subclass.

Comment: doesnt work in androidstudio, Cmd-O opens the class file.

Comment: It's Ctrl-O, not Cmd-O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kotlin.List<out T>` and `kotlin.MutableList<E>` [are mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), which, on the JVM and Android, are both represented by the `java.util.List<E>` interface.

So you just need to use the Java `List<E>` type wherever you need to inter-operate with the Kotlin `List<out E>` or `MutableList<E>`.